# Dynamic Scopes for pac4j JEE based application

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pac4j

Currently I am using Pac4j jee-pac4j.version 5.0.1-SNAPSHOT in JAVA 8 ,
I have a scenario where  I need to inject the scope externally to test my application with different scope settings passed through a UI.

Is there any possible way i can do this.

[GitHub Project refered](https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/tree/5.0.x)

Can you please suggest me a solution for the same.

I tried extending DemoConfigFactory Class and setScope for each client retriving them through config:

```
configFactory.build("openid profile").getClients().getClients().forEach(client -> {
                if (client instanceof GoogleOidcClient) {
                    GoogleOidcClient oidcClient = (GoogleOidcClient) client;
                    oidcClient.getConfiguration().setScope(selectedScope);
                                    }
            });
```

its not adding the scopes or updating in the Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, clients are lazily initialized so if the client is already initialized, you can't change its configuration.

Why not update the `XXXConfigFactory` and set the scope at this stage?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution, I have configured the scopes at XXXConfigFactory but Actually I had a requirement for my client application to pass the scopes dynamically with each request ,so is there a workaround for the same , any class i can extend or implement so that i could add the scopes and update the Existing configuration?